# MVC DropDownList recuperar datos de model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy intentando setear el valor seleccionado de un dropdownlist desde la información de la base de datos.

Cargo una lista desde el controlador:

```
public void cargarMotivosFinalizacion()
{
    ViewBag.motivosFinalizacion = db.SFI_AtributosDbSet.Where
    (x => x.Tipo_Atributo == "MOTIVO FINALIZACION").OrderBy(x =>                 
    x.Descrip_Atributo).Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
         Text = x.Descrip_Atributo,
         Value = x.ID_Atributo
    }).ToList();
}
```

Motivo_Finalizacion en la base de datos tiene el código que debería estar seleccionado en el dropdown pero no funciona.
Aparentemente hay muchas cosas que estoy haciendo mal pero es mi primer proyecto y no se cual seria la forma correcta.

El modelo es:

```
public class SFI_Salarios
{
    [Key]                
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    //[ForeignKey("usuario")]        
    public string Win_User_ID { get; set; }

    public string CUIL { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public decimal Salario_Base { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 3)]  
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Fecha de Inicio obligatoria")]        
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public string Fecha_Inicio { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public string Fecha_Fin { get; set; }
    public string Motivo_Finalizacion { get; set; }
    public string Otros_1 { get; set; }

    public virtual SFI_Usuarios usuario { get; set; }


}
```

Vista:

```
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;


@model IPagedList<sfi_1.Models.SFI_Salarios>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Salarios";
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/funcionesJS.js")"></script>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        cambiarFormatoFechaIndex();
    })
</script>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Index_Deshabilitados", "SFI_Salarios", FormMethod.Get))
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listaVendedores = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.vendedores;
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listaMotivos = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.motivosFinalizacion;   

<table class="table">
    <tr><th></th></tr>
    <tr>
        <th><h2>SALARIOS HISTORICOS</h2></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    @Html.DropDownList("vendedor", listaVendedores, "Seleccionar Vendedor", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "IndexSalarioVendedor" })
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span>Buscar</span></button>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Nuevo Salario", "Create", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                    @Html.ActionLink("Limpiar Filtro", "Index", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                    @Html.ActionLink("Mostrar Habilitados", "Index", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })

                </div>
            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>


<table class="table" id="tablaIndexSalarios">

    <tr>
        <th>ID Usuario</th>
        <th>Nombre Vendedor</th>
        <th>Salario</th>
        <th>Fecha Inicio</th>
        <th>Fecha Fin</th>
        <th>Observaciones</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Win_User_ID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.usuario.Nombre)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Salario_Base)
            </td>
            <td id="fechaInicio">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fecha_Inicio)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fecha_Fin)
            </td>
            <td>                                
                @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.Motivo_Finalizacion, listaMotivos, "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "IndexSalarioVendedor" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edit", new { winUser = item.Win_User_ID, fecha = item.Fecha_Inicio }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-primary " })
                @Html.ActionLink("Borrar", "Delete", new { winUser = item.Win_User_ID, fecha = item.Fecha_Inicio }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-primary " })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
}

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

Controlador que carga los datos:

```
public ActionResult Index_Deshabilitados(string vendedor, int? page)
    {
        try
        {
            if (HttpContext.Application["codigoPerfilUsuario"].ToString() == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", null);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", null);
        }

        if (!validacionUsuario("Otros_2"))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("usuarioNoHabilitado");
        }
        cargarListaVendedores();
        cargarMotivosFinalizacion();


        return View(db.SFI_Salarios.Where(x =>
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vendedor) ? true : x.Win_User_ID == vendedor))//.OrderBy(x=> x.usuario.Nombre)
        .OrderBy(x => x.usuario.Nombre).ThenBy(x => x.Fecha_Inicio).ThenBy(x => x.Fecha_Fin).ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 20));


    }
```

Comment: En teoría tu código está correcto, el select debería de tomar como opción seleccionada el valor que tienes en tu propiedad Motivo_Finalizacion de tu modelo. Pero creo falta nos muestres más código para entender más a detalle tu problema. Por ejemplo, que modelo le estas pasando a la vista (parece ser le estas pasando una lista) y como es que vienen los valor en ese modelo.

Comment: Ahi lo edite y puse mas informacion :D

Comment: No he encontrado la solucion para esto